# My AddForce method is not working or pushing a Rigidbody2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my first question and I'm new on game development so please if it's kinda stupid don't be tough.

My problem is that I detected de collision between my enemy and my player on the enemy script, and I want it to push back the player backwards the collision point.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            float force = 200f;
            Vector3 dir = (Vector3)collision.contacts[0].point - transform.position;
            dir = -dir.normalized;
            collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity += (Vector2)dir * force;
            Debug.Log("Collided");
        }
    }
```

Once it collides, i get the debug.log info on the console. but there's not any kind of force applied to it.

I tried to use the AddForce method too, but it neither works.

I'm a bit stuck on the code, but I hope anyone else can help me to figure out what's the problem.

Comment: try using `Rigidbody2D.AddForce(force, ForceMode2D.Impulse)` this might work for you.

Comment: Not working neither... Idk what is wrong with them...

Comment: Can you show me the constraints of the `Rigidbody`, and also check if you are getting a Null Reference exception when you make changes in the rigid body.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you add the velocity in global space, but the collision point you use is in local space. my soulution would be to use the following formula to calculate the direction.

```
Vector3 dir = collision.transform.position - transform.position;
dir = dir.normalized;
```

Because here i used the position (that is global) of the two objects to calculate the direction vector, my result will be also in global space.

My advice is that you always think trough in what space (in relation to the object or in relation to the world origin) are the cordinates that you use.
I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: The player is still not being pushed. I tried the same with the enemies, but neither works.

Comment: Could you show your current script that is not working, so i might be able to find the problem?

Comment: i uploaded it on a new reply

Comment: But... you didn't

Comment: Also, did you try using the CompareTag("tag") method instead of .tag == "tag"